# How to attain value from the same table

Tags: mysql

Now I want to get a comments list, and I have two table named TB_COMMENT, TB_USER;
the TB_COMMENT table has three fields: WORK_ID, USER_ID, ATED_USER_ID；
the TB_USER table has three fields: USER_ID, NICKNAME.
now the front end gives me a workId, and I need to return the list include:
userId, nickname, atedUserId, atedNickname.(and the atedUserId, atedNickname may not exist).
And I just write this sql sentence:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TB_USER.USER_ID, TB_USER.NICKNAME, TB_COMMENT.ATED_USER_ID
FROM TB_USER, TB_COMMENT 
WHERE TB_COMMENT.WORK_ID = #{workId} AND TB_COMMENT.USER_ID = TB_USER.USER_ID`
```

and I don't know how to get the atedNickname. Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: Which table has `atedNickname` column?

Comment: no, it's just the NICKNAME but from the ATED_USER_ID

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more join with `TB_USER` on `ATED_USER_ID` foreign key

```
SELECT DISTINCT ua.USER_ID, ua.NICKNAME, ub.USER_ID, ub.NICKNAME
FROM TB_USER ua INNER JOIN TB_COMMENT c ON ua.USER_ID = c.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN TB_USER ub ON ub.USER_ID = c.ATED_USER_ID
WHERE c.WORK_ID = #{workId}
```

Comment: @qbout you're welcome :) Also, please don't forget to upvote / accept the answer which are helpful.

Comment: now， the problem is the ATED_USER_ID may not exists, when it doesn't exist, it can't get the records. Do you have any approach? I'm sorry I didn't ask it clearly before.

Comment: I say doesn't exist means the value is null

Comment: @qbout changes made in the answer... last join should be left join for your requirement